# Meteor.call in for each loop runs in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, meteor, react-hooks

Meteor newbie here, I have list loop that does a meteor call to the meteor method. I need the results populated in another object with each list item as key and value as the meteor method response.
After all the item related meteor calls are done returning responses, I want to print the  completely updated object in the end

This is my following code and it runs in an infinite loop

```js
  const [codeCoverage, setcodeCoverage] = useState({});
  projectList = ['proj1','proj2','proj3']
  projectList.map((project) => {
    Meteor.call(
      'sonarqb.getProjectStatus',
      { project },
      (error, resp) => {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
        setCodeCoverage({...codeCoverage, [project] : val.actualValue })
      }
    )
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(codeCoverage);
  }, [codeCoverage]);
```

Meteor Method serving the above call

```js
Meteor.methods({
  'sonarqb.getProjectStatus'({ project }) {

    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: `https://sonarqube.com/sonar/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=${project}`,
      headers: {
        Authorization:
          'Basic <auth str>',
      },
    };

    const future = new Future();

    request(options, function(error, response) {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);
      const sonarResponse = JSON.parse(response.body);
      future.return(sonarResponse);
    });
    return future.wait();
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a React function component, the issue is that your `Meteor.call`s happen every time the component renders, which includes every time you call `setCodeCoverage`, i.e., every time a call completes — hence an infinite loop.

You need to wrap the `Meteor.call`s in a `useEffect` (or something), not have them at the top level of your component.  If you want them to just happen once at the beginning of your component:

```js
  const [codeCoverage, setcodeCoverage] = useState({});
  const projectList = ['proj1','proj2','proj3'];
  useEffect(() => {
    projectList.forEach((project) => {
      Meteor.call(
        'sonarqb.getProjectStatus',
        { project },
        (error, resp) => {
          if (error) throw new Error(error);
          setCodeCoverage((previous) =>
            {...previous, [project] : val.actualValue });
        }
      )
    })
  }, []); // no deps => run once at beginning

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(codeCoverage);
  }, [codeCoverage]);
```

Comment: thanks for explaining it, that did stop the infinite loop. However the object i am trying to update `setCodeCoverage({...codeCoverage, [project] : 
val.actualValue })` is getting overwritten. I expected to get `{"proj1":1,"proj2":2,"proj3":3,"proj4":4}` but i am getting `{"proj1":1}` and this gets over written by `{"proj2":2}`, `{"proj3":3}`, `{"proj4":4}`. From my research, seems like this is how to update the object but not sure why its getting overwritten, any ideas?

Comment: Oops, I missed that bug. New code above should fix it. The issue here is that `codeCoverage` was set to the initial value of the state, and will be in the closure of all the `Meteor.call` callbacks. React has no way to update it (except in future renders). To fix this, you can use the function form of `setCodeCoverage` which gives as argument the (updated) previous value. See code above.